# What does the 'indeterminate' mean in ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

Maybe my English is poor but I really cannot figure out what the "*indeterminate*" means in this context:

Android Development → [`ProgressDialog.isIndeterminate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#isIndeterminate%28%29)

Comment: indetermine means Dont Determine progress.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It means the "loading amount" is not measured.

Answer (score 37):

From wiktionary:
Indeterminate: Not accurately determined or determinable.
It basically just means you're unsure how long the action will take so you cannot say for example something is 50% done.

This normally just means the progress will be displayed as a constantly moving loading bar rather than a percentage or the like.

Answer (score 19):

Basically when `setProgressStyle(ProgressDialoge.STYLE_SPINNER)` is taken then `setIndeterminate()` will be true because a `circle(Spinner)` will rotate, which shows that "do not know how much time it is going to take". When take `ProgressStyle(ProgressDialoge.STYLE_HORIZANTAL)` we will take `setIndeterminate()` as false since it take a value/percentage bar like how much percentage it was completed with `setProgress(value)`.

Answer (score 2):

In simple language we can say when the amount is not determined means we don't know how much it gonna be to be completed or loaded fully..!!

Answer (score 0):

> Change the indeterminate mode for this ProgressDialog. In
>   indeterminate mode, the progress is ignored and the dialog shows an
>   infinite animation instead.
>
> Note: A ProgressDialog with style STYLE_SPINNER is always
>   indeterminate and will ignore this setting.
>   Blockquote

For illustration, the progress animation keep loading from left to right and then repeat automatically without user interaction(which setProgress) when `indeterminate` set to `true`.

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).